# Strange shading behaviour with normal maps in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, procedural-generation, normals

I've been having some very strange lighting behaviour in Unreal 4. In short, here's what I mean:

[image]

Fig 1, First, without any normal mapping on the bricks.

[image]

Fig 2, Now with a normal map applied, generated based on the same black-and-white brick texture.

[image]

Fig 3, The base pixel normals of the objects in question.

[image]

Fig 4, The generated normals which get applied.

[image]

Fig 5, The material node setup which produces the issue, as shown in Fig 2

As you can see, the issue occurs when using the generated HeightToNormalSmooth node. As shown, this is not an issue relating to object normals (see Fig 3) or to a badly exported normal map (as there isn't one in the traditional sense), nor is it an issue with the HeightToNormalSmooth node itself (Fig 4 shows that it generates the correct bump normals).

To be clear, the issue here is the fact that using a normal texture at all (this issue occurs across all my materials) causes the positive Y facing faces of an object to turn completely black (or it seems, to become purely reflections-based, as increasing roughness on the material causes the black faces to become less 'shiny' looking).

This is really strange, I've tested with multiple different skylight setups, sun directions, and yet this always happens (even when lit directly), but only on +Y aligned faces.

If anyone can offer insight that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've discovered why this was an issue. Turns out there's a little option in the material settings called 'Tangent Space Normal'. This is on by default ('for convenience'), disabling this appears to completely fix the issue with the generated normal maps produced by HeightToNormalSmooth.

Answer (score 0):

You're subtracting what looks like 1 from the input that then goes into multiply by 1, if I'm correct. This will, in most cases, make any image return black. This is because in UE4 and many other programs, colors in an image are determined by decimals of Red Green and Blue. These decimals fall in a range of 0 to 1. This means if I wanted to make red, I could use these values- R = 1 G = 0 B = 0. This matters because if R = 0 G = 0 B = 0, the result is black. When you use a multiply node in your example, what you are doing is having UE4 take each pixel of the image you fed into the node (if it was white, R = 1 G = 1 B = 1) and multiply its R, G, and B values by that number. Since zero multiplied by a number equals zero, all the pixels in the image are being set to have values of R = 0, G = 0, and B = 0. thus, all zeros, and you get black.

I also noticed you then multiplied it by one, which in most cases won't do a whole lot, since you're just multiplying the input by 1. If your input is 0, (black), multiplying it by one won't change it, cause 0 * 1 still equals 0.

To fix your issue, try changing the value you subtract from your input to be something smaller than one, say a decimal, such as 0.6 or 0.5

Comment: hey thanks, I'm already well aware of how colours work in unreal and computers in general. UE4 passes negative colours through, they simply get rendered out to the screen as black, and the HeightToNormalSmooth node seems to be happy accepting negative-ranged inputs. I have verified this, and I've verified that the same strange behaviour described above still occurs regardless of the 'subtract 1' node being present or not. thanks for the suggestion though